# Formatting dates coming from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Grails, if I define a locale, and put a date on specific format on i18n file, like (dd/mm/AAAA), if call one request like:

```
http://myapp/myaction?object.date=10/12/2013
```

When I get print: params.date, it comes to me a date object.

How can I do the same on rails?

Comment: To do that I do this: `DateTime.parse('10/12/2013')`, is that what you need?

Comment: Hi Gerep, if I do this, i Will need to intercept all my requests. What i need is: MyModel.new (params[:object]). By Default if I define my date format as dd/mm/AAAA, rails will convert params to object correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the Rails handles this for you. For instance, the form helper `datetime_select` works in conjunction with some [activerecord magic](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d90b4e2/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L1811)
to ensure ensure time/date types survive the round-trip. There are various alternatives to the standard date-pickers.

If this doesn't work for you e.g. rails isn't generating the forms, there are (at least) a couple of options.

One option, slightly evi, is to monkey-patch `HashWithIndifferentAccess` (used by request params) to do type conversions based on the key name. It could look something like:

```
module AddTypedKeys

  def [](key)
    key?(key) ? super : find_candidate(key.to_s)
  end

private

  # look for key with a type extension  
  def find_candidate(key)
    keys.each do |k|
      name, type = k.split('.', 2)
      return typify_param(self[k], type) if name == key
    end
    nil
  end

  def typify_param(value, type)
    case type
      when 'date'
        value.to_date rescue nil
      else
        value
    end
  end   
end


HashWithIndifferentAccess.send(:include, AddTypedKeys)
```

This will extend params[] in the way you describe. To use it within rais, you can drop it into an initialiser, eg `confg/initializers/typed_params.rb`

To see it working, you can test with

```
params = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({'a' => 'hello', 'b.date' => '10/1/2013', 'c.date' => 'bob'})
puts params['b.date'] # returns string 
puts params['b'] # returns timestamp
puts params['a'] # returns string
puts params['c'] # nil (invalid date parsed)
```

However... I'm not sure it's worth the effort, and it will likely not work with Rails 4 / StrongParameters.

A better solution would be using *virtual attributes* in your models. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296995/how-to-use-chronic-to-parse-dates-in-a-datetime-text-field) for a really good example using chronic.